# How to use automatic reference counting and virtual functions together in the C++?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, shared-ptr, virtual-functions

I had been searching the answer for this problem for a long.

I want to use shared data (shared_ptr or something similar) where it's possible and where it's necessary of course. But I also want to use virtual functions. As you can see below, there is a contradiction in the usage of them together.

I protect the data of class in this manner:

```
class MyObject {
public:
    void method() {
        // no memory leak here, because this contains
        // count of references of Data inside shared_ptr
        OtherObject::otherMethod(this);
    }
private:
    class Data {};
    shared_ptr<Data> data;
};
```

Because if I simply nest my class MyObject inside the shared_ptr, I will not be able to pass "this" raw pointer safely outside of the MyObject class in some method. Raw pointer is not protected with reference counting.

Example:

```
class MyObject {
public:
    void method() {
        // memory leak here, because this does not contain
        // count of references of Data or of self (MyObject) 
        OtherObject::otherMethod(this);
    }
private:
    class Data {};
    Data data;
};

...

shared_ptr<MyObject> crazyLeakingObject;
```

crazyLeakingObject leaks, because it has MyObject inside with all its data and methods, but it is only MyObject without any information about count of the references. In the MyObject's methods we have no such information.

The first approach I use when I do not need virtual functions. But the second is for the virtual functions. As you know, you can access vtable only through pointer (raw pointer) of the existing object. But raw pointers and protected shared pointers are opposites.
Usage of this two approaches together makes the architecture of my projects messy.
And there is a leaks in the second approach.

Is there a way to use virtual functions and automatic reference counting? Where I can find an examples? Did you faced with the problem?

I am not a native English speaker, so you may ask for the clarifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I must confess total confusion over what you are trying to achieve. Regardless, with the code you have supplied, there is no memory leak.

Comment: `shared_ptr<MyObject> crazyLeakingObject;` does not leak anything. It doesn't even create an instance of `MyObject`, just an empty shared_ptr. I think you need to show more code, with an example of something that leaks.

Comment: The question is a complete mess. I recommend that you sit down for a couple of minutes, reconsider what really bothers you and write a simpler question. Some of the things that are not clear: the title mentions *virtual functions*, but there is no other mention in the whole question. It is not clear what `otherMethod` is, what the arguments should be and/or what the expected behavior is (the important part is whether it only *uses* the argument or if it can also *store* it for later use, say in a member variable). The `crazyLeakingObject` does not *leak* per se, can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use virtual functions with `shared_ptr`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void foo() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void foo() { std::cout << "derived\n"; }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Base> ptr(new Derived());
    ptr->foo(); // prints "derived"
} // object is deleted at function return
```

If your `OtherObject::otherMethod` stores its argument away somewhere, such that it can last longer than the caller's reference, then you might have a problem. You could pass a `shared_ptr` to `otherMethod` instead of a raw pointer, and use Boost's `enable_shared_from_this` so that the code in `method` can get the shared pointer to the object itself, to pass to `otherMethod`. But without seeing any of the relevant code, I don't know whether or not it's necessary or a good idea.

Comment: One justification for using `shared_ptr` is that you can't copy, because the objects are polymorphic.  And with regards to generating new pointers from `this`, I've found `boost::invasive_ptr` to be very effective here.

Comment: That would compile better:-).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use enable_shared_from_this. That's what I tried to wrote myself. Did not mind that it can be in the C++ std.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use std::enable_shared_from_this to pass the this pointer of a shared object...

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/enable_shared_from_this